# Show all icons defined in a css file

Tags: css, icons

Since I am pretty bad at graphic design and my CSS skills are not so good, I usually buy pure HTML/CSS templates to start new (small) websites.
The problem is that usually these templates are bloated with unused JS/CSS or, at the opposite end, they use only a subset of open source icon packs for example.
So I usually have CSS files with this (of course, just an example):

```
.icon-email2:before {
    content: "\e662";
}
.icon-heart2:before {
    content: "\e663";
}
.icon-enter:before {
    content: "\e664";
}
.icon-cloud1:before {
    content: "\e665";
}
.icon-book2:before {
    content: "\e666";
}
.icon-star2:before {
    content: "\e667";
}
```

Is there an easy way to print a table with "css name / icon" for ALL the styles defined in that CSS file? So I can visually see what I have and especially what I don't have.
I can (with PHP) build a parser to generate the corresponding HTML file, but I was wondering if there is a nicer, cleaner, faster option in JS and/or CSS itself.